# Pyqtgraph.opengl GLSurfacePlotItem : How to get multiple colors with height?

Tags: python, image, 3d, pyqtgraph

I am plotting a 3d_image using **GLSurfacePlotItem**.
My Z-axis Data lies between 0 - 255

```
gl.GLSurfacePlotItem(x=x[:, 0], y=y[0, :], shader='heightColor', computeNormals=False, smooth=False)
```

Following is the ColorMap:

```
p4.shader()['colorMap'] = np.array([0.45, 0, 0.1, 0.005, 0.5, 2, 0, 0.05, 0.2])
```

I do get some color shade in the output image but would like to know how can i enable multiple colors in the same

- Thanks

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem, I love the speed of pyqtgraph, but the documentation is sorely lacking a tutorial, and more detailed explanations of the various data structures used

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following answer on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/g/pyqtgraph/c/dJmjMs1SDYc?pli=1) , which I am copying across here, as it is the first item I have come across on the web giving details of how the colormap works on pyqtgraph for 3d plots

### copied across from google groups

Hi,

Yeah, the GL stuff doesn't use the same colour maps as the 2D images. I can't see any documentation on the shaders (http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/3dgraphics/glmeshitem.html) that are used to colour the surface. Looking at the code under shaders.py does help though. For the "heightColor" shader, the 9 numbers in the array that are used (as in the Surface Plot example) are variables used in a formula to compute the RGB colour.

From comment in code:

```
## colors fragments by z-value.
## This is useful for coloring surface plots by height.
## This shader uses a uniform called "colorMap" to determine how to map the colors:
##    red   = pow(z * colorMap[0] + colorMap[1], colorMap[2])
##    green = pow(z * colorMap[3] + colorMap[4], colorMap[5])
##    blue  = pow(z * colorMap[6] + colorMap[7], colorMap[8])
## (set the values like this: shader['uniformMap'] = array([...])
```

I assume the output RGB values are expressed as a range from 0 to 1. So to tweak the example to work with ranges from say zmin to zmax, I think something like:

```
p4.shader()['colorMap'] = np.array([0.2*(zmax - zmin), 2 - zmin, 0.5, 0.2*(zmax - zmin), 1 - zmin, 1, 0.2*(zmax - zmin), 0 - zmin, 2])
```

Patrick